# как правильно перенаправить все файлы, содержащиеся в каталоге, на /dev/null?

Tags: linux, bash

как правильно перенаправить все файлы, содержащиеся в каталоге, на /dev/null?
пробовал

```
*>/dev/null
```

не выходит.

Comment: То есть их содержимое? Пройдите циклом по всем файлам и воспользуйтесь командой `cat`.

Comment: `/dev/null ` - это условное символьное устройство. Что значит перенаправить туда файлы?

Comment: Мне просто нужно , грубо говоря, очищать автоматические содержимое каталога, поэтому хочу перенаправлять содержимое каталога на /dev/null , чтобы каталог был совершенно пустой. Так как из-за этого постоянно забивается место на сервере.

Comment: Вам нужно удалить содержимое всех файлов в каталоге? Тогда просто `truncate --size=0 /path/to/files/*`

Comment: @EOF она будет автоматически вычищать полностью каталог?

Comment: Она удалит содержимое всех файлов в каталоге в тот момент, когда вы выполните эту команду.

Comment: @maestro а есть вариант, чтобы при появлении там файлов, команда автоматически удаляла его и каталог всегда был бы путсым

Comment: Я могу подсказать только запускать эту команду периодически по cron. Спецы, может, подскажут более оптимальное решение. А чтобы удалить все файлы, а не очистить их содержимое, есть команда `rm -rf`

Comment: @maestro это да, я просто вот как раз и думал, может как-то все содержимое перенаправлять на /dev/null

Comment: А может, лучше решать исходную проблему и в принципе отключить запись в программе-виновнике?